# Web Traffic Analytics to Play Nice with ASP.NET MVC, Signalr

Tags: asp.net-mvc, statistics, analytics, signalr

For a project I am looking to provide extensive analytics based on web traffic hitting pages generated by the users of the site. Think Wordpress-like and analytics like Google.

I know it's almost reinventing the wheel and I could be using Google Analytics but the project requires the stats collected to be private. I would love to have something like [Hummingbird](http://projects.nuttnet.net/hummingbird/), [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) comes close. But it's not production ready yet. Writing one from scratch is an option too.

Something like [OWA](http://wiki.openwebanalytics.com/index.php?title=Main_Page) would be perfect as well.

So the question is two part here,

1. What are some great (if any) tools that can be used to collect and then customize web traffic stats? (Is there one built on Signalr, I would love to see one!)
2. If I were to write one what would be the starting blocks and data structures?

Comment: why aren't you using OWA? is there any reason? because it looks really great!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at http://loggr.net/. It's build with SignalR.